# scope of const auto variables

Tags: c++, scope, auto

I have a simple function

```
void simpleFunction(){

const auto img= getImageSomehow();

// do something with img
}
```

it works ok. However I want to modify this function to include a boolean there as:

```
void simpleFunction(bool isGPU){

if(isGPU){
        const auto img= getImagefromGPU();
}
else{
    const auto img= getImageSomehow();
}
// do something with img
}
```

However this is not correct right? since the scope of the auto variable `img` does not reach the operations in "do something with img"

This does not work either

```
void simpleFunction(bool isGPU){
 const auto img;    
if(isGPU){
        img= getImagefromGPU();
}
else{
    img= getImageSomehow();
}
// do something with img
}
```

since the declaration has no initializer.

Is there a way to somehow do this?  in other words, get the img depending on the bool and then work with it?

Comment: Do the 2 functions that you use to initialize `img` return the same type?

Comment: Are these both the same type, or are they completely different types? If you had a consistent `Image` type you wouldn't need `auto`.

Comment: they are different types (one is a CPU variable, the other one a GPU one)

Comment: If they're different types, what exactly are you doing with `img` after the initialization, that works for either type?

Comment: @cigien That is a good point. The thing is that simpleFunction has a logic that works the same for both types of `img` but only when calling operations with `img` I have to make the distinction. Perhaps I should write two completely separated functions but repeat the logic...

Comment: @cigien btw, the answer that you deleted seemed interesting but I suppose that worked only for same types?..

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the types were the same. BTW, *don't* repeat the logic; that's not a good solution. There are other ways to refactor it though, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @cigien  Thanks. Wont do. Though it was interesting to read about the `[=]`

Comment: I edited the answer into a solution that should work for your use case.

Comment: Assuming the functions return the same type,   `const auto img = isGPU ? getImagefromGPU() : getImageSomehow()` will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to refactor the code that "does something with img" into a template

```
template<typename ImageType>
void do_something(ImageType const img)  // img is const here as desired
{
  // do something with img
}
```

and then your original function becomes

```
void simpleFunction(bool isGPU)
{
  if(isGPU) 
    do_something(getImagefromGPU());
  else
    do_something(getImageSomehow());
}
```

Comment: If these are different types that's a big nope. The ternary can have an arbitrary type, but it must have a *consistent* type.

Comment: @tadman That's true. Fixable with an `if constexpr` but I'll get clarification from the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That seems really interesting. Will check it I can make it work in my project

Answer (score 1):

The scope rules don't change. The scopes remain the same. The only thing that's different is the type.

The `auto` keyword might seem magical, but it's actually quite simple. **It cannot predict the future**. This means branches that return different types are non-viable.

As such, you can't define an empty `auto` and later populate it. You also can't declare an `auto` inside a block and expect it to be visible outside of that block.

What you need is to avoid `auto`, and instead use a singular type that can accommodate both cases, or you can use inheritance to pave over the differences. You can then have a factory method to get the right kind of "image getter" and call `getImage()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to highlight your errors in your code before offering a solution.

```cpp
void simpleFunction(bool isGPU) {
  if (isGPU) {
    const auto img = getImagefromGPU();
  }
  else {
    const auto img = getImageSomehow();
  }

  // do something with img
}
```

in this code, `img` is declared within the scope of the if/else blocks, meaning it will not be visible outside of them. You simply cannot use `img` outside of their scope, given the way you chose to declare `img`.

```cpp
void simpleFunction(bool isGPU) {
  const auto img;   
 
  if (isGPU) {
    img = getImagefromGPU();
  }
  else {
    img = getImageSomehow();
  }
  
  // do something with img
}
```

Here, although you have resolved the scoping issue, by declaring the variable outside of the if/else block, you create a problem by using the `auto` keyword. `auto` cannot resolve the type because you do not declare an assignment immediately. As a result, you get the error of no initializer, since the compiler cannot resolve what type fits for the `img` declaration.

With that in mind, there are some solutions.

You may use the ternary operator, or you may declare the type directly, rather than using `auto`.

```cpp
// ternary

const auto img = isGPU ? getImagefromGPU() : getImageSomehow();

// type declaration

const Image img;

if (isGPU) {
  img = getImagefromGPU();
}
else {
  img = getImageSomehow();
}
```

Comment: thanks. The complication is that `getImageFromGPU` returns a different type than `getImageSomehow` so not sure if the ternary would work

Comment: hmm, your code implied that the types would somehow be the same. `auto` cannot dynamically change the type, as its not a runtime type declaration, but a compile-time declaration, meaning the type is not versatile. If the types extend a common class, use that type, otherwise create some commonality between the classes so that the types can be shared, such as a common superclass.

Comment: yes thanks I realize that. I think the simplest bet would be to use cigien's solution with templates